# Webpack shows white screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

After I've added webpack in my react app, once the webpack started, it shows the white screen, and the whole bundle gets downloaded at one time. Even though I've done code splitting in react.

my webpack config:

```
 /* eslint-disable no-un`enter code here`def */
    const path = require("path");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const HtmlWebpackInjectPreload = require("@principalstudio/html-webpack-inject-preload");
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
    
    module.exports = {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.js'),
      devtool: "inline-source-map",
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/'
      },
      devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        port: 4000,
        hot: true,
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".*",".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
        fallback: {
          stream: false
        }
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: ["babel-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /\.module\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.module\.css$/,
            use: [
              "style-loader",
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: { importLoaders: 2, modules: true },
              },
              "postcss-loader",
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                  limit: 8192,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: path.resolve('./index.html')
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackInjectPreload({
          files: [
            {
              match: /.*\.woff2$/,
              attributes: { as: "font", type: "font/woff2", crossorigin: true },
            },
            {
              match: /\.[a-z-0-9]*.css$/,
              attributes: { as: "style" },
            },
          ],
        }),
      ],
    };
```

The attached bundle image also gets larger up to 19MB. What's going wrong I'm not able to figure out.

[image]